Why do we require substitutability in this case?
I have these two quantifier axioms:
$(\forall x \phi)\rightarrow \phi_t^x$,  if t is substitutable for x in $\phi$.
$\phi_t^x\rightarrow (\exists x \phi)$, if t is substitutable for x in $\phi$.
We can see that the first axiom require subsitutability if we look at $\phi(x)=\exists y (x\neq y)$. Then $\forall x \phi (x)$ is true(if the structure has atleast two elements), but if $t=y$ and we substitute y we get $\phi _y^x$ is $\exists y (y \neq y)$ and this is not true.
Do you have an example like this to show that we need substitutability in the second case as well?

Exactly.
Contrapose it to get $\lnot \exists y \lnot (y=y) \to \lnot \forall x \exists y \lnot (x=y)$ that is: $\forall y (y=y) \to \exists x \forall y (x=y)$.
Thus, the counter-example is with $\forall y (x=y)$ as $\phi$ and $y$ as $t$.
